# CakePHP built in web server: can you specify the PHP binary that's used

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP there is a [built in web server](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/installation.html#development-server) that can be used for development.

This can be started with `bin/cake server` which then serves the application by default on http://localhost:8765

In my case I have an old CakePHP 3.8.13 application. On my MacBook the global `php` executable is PHP version 8:

```
% php -v
PHP 8.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2023 15:36:37) ( NTS )
```

This is problematic because CakePHP 3.8.13 is not designed to run on PHP 8. It works on PHP 7.

On my MacBook I have PHP versions 7.1, 7.2, 7.3 and 8.0 installed in `/usr/local/opt/`. These have been installed with brew. So if I want to execute PHP version 7.2 I can do it like this:

```
% /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php -v
PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2023 06:18:05) ( NTS )
```

The question I have is: how can I make `bin/cake server` use a binary such as PHP 7.2, rather than the globally installed version PHP 8?

I tried `alias php=/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php` and this initially appears to work in that when subsequently executing `php` it uses the appropriate version:

```
% alias php=/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php
% php -v
PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2023 06:18:05) ( NTS )
```

However, if I then stop and restart the inbuilt CakePHP web server it says the following in the logs:

```
% bin/cake server
built-in server is running in http://localhost:8765/
You can exit with `CTRL-C`
[Wed Apr 19 09:35:19 2023] PHP 8.0.27 Development Server (http://localhost:8765) started
```

Notice that this is using PHP 8.0.27 which isn't what I want.

Comment: This is actually using PHP's built-in server, this is not Cake-specific. I think switching to having your PHP versions managed by Homebrew might be a good idea, https://romanmiranda.com/switch-between-php-versions-in-mac-with-homebrew-sphp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server command creates a new shell via PHP's `system()` call, and aliases do not propagate into sub-shells.

As of CakePHP 4.1.6 the server command recognizes the `PHP` environment variable, so that you could do something like:

```bash
export PHP=/path/to/php ; bin/cake server
```

With earlier versions you could either create your own CakePHP command that uses an environment variable, start the PHP built-in server manually (`/path/to/php -S localhost:8765 -t /path/to/webroot/`), or manage PHP versions with for example Homebrew [**as mentioned by @Cbroe**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76052373/cakephp-built-in-web-server-can-you-specify-the-php-binary-thats-used#comment134130123_76052373) in the comments.